# How do I complete the Surveilence Merc Mission?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

Once you acquire Azami, you can do a Merc Mission called Surveilence. It has a completion time of ??:??:??, but does that mean it's a randomly generated time, or some other event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a quest that will appear in the Fonsa Myma docks/port area called "All's Well" - you need to have Pyra (and supposedly Morag) in your party for this to show up in the world.